# How to multiply every column of one Pandas Dataframe with every column of another Dataframe efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to multiply two pandas dataframes with each other. Specifically, I want to multiply every column with every column of the other df.

The dataframes are one-hot encoded, so they look like this:

```
col_1, col_2, col_3, ...
 0      1      0 
 1      0      0 
 0      0      1 
 ...
```

I could just iterate through each of the columns using a for loop, but in python that is computationally expensive, and I'm hoping there's an easier way.

One of the dataframes has 500 columns, the other has 100 columns.

This is the fastest version that I've been able to write so far:

```
interact_pd = pd.DataFrame(index=df_1.index)
df1_columns = [column for column in df_1]
for column in df_2:
    col_pd = df_1[df1_columns].multiply(df_2[column], axis="index")
    interact_pd = interact_pd.join(col_pd, lsuffix='_' + column)
```

I iterate over each column in df_2 and multiply all of df_1 by that column, then I append the result to interact_pd. I would rather not do it using a for loop however, as this is very computationally costly. Is there a faster way of doing it?

EDIT: example

df_1:

```
1col_1, 1col_2, 1col_3
 0      1      0 
 1      0      0 
 0      0      1
```

df_2:

```
2col_1, 2col_2
 0      1       
 1      0       
 0      0
```

interact_pd:

```
1col_1_2col_1, 1col_2_2col_1,1col_3_2col_1, 1col_1_2col_2, 1col_2_2col_2,1col_3_2col_2

  0      0      0        0       1        0  
  1      0      0        0       0        0 
  0      0      0        0       0        0
```

Comment: you need to produce as reproducible example if what you've tried, clearly show what you're desired output is, and explain the shortcomings of your previous efforts.

Comment: What do you mean by interaction?

Comment: just edited the question - does it make more sense?

Comment: Show us 2 (short) df and the corresponding output you expect.

Comment: How do you want to multiply every column of your first data frame witt each column of your second data frame if they have a different count of columns? Are you aiming for a result with 50000 columns?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I mean

Comment: Just a cosmetic thing, you can just do `df1_columns = df1.columns` in line 2.

Comment: You should accept @piRSquared's solution, not mine, it's around 10 times faster than my code for larger datasets.

Comment: thanks, these answers were awesome and super helpful!

Comment: @chris see my solution which is faster than the accepted one on a dataset similar to yours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
# use numpy to get a pair of indices that map out every
# combination of columns from df_1 and columns of df_2
pidx = np.indices((df_1.shape[1], df_2.shape[1])).reshape(2, -1)

# use pandas MultiIndex to create a nice MultiIndex for
# the final output
lcol = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df_1.columns, df_2.columns],
                                  names=[df_1.columns.name, df_2.columns.name])

# df_1.values[:, pidx[0]] slices df_1 values for every combination
# like wise with df_2.values[:, pidx[1]]
# finally, I marry up the product of arrays with the MultiIndex
pd.DataFrame(df_1.values[:, pidx[0]] * df_2.values[:, pidx[1]],
             columns=lcol)
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

**code**

```
from string import ascii_letters

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (1000, 26)), columns=list(ascii_letters[:26]))
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (1000, 52)), columns=list(ascii_letters))

def pir1(df_1, df_2):
    pidx = np.indices((df_1.shape[1], df_2.shape[1])).reshape(2, -1)

    lcol = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df_1.columns, df_2.columns],
                                      names=[df_1.columns.name, df_2.columns.name])

    return pd.DataFrame(df_1.values[:, pidx[0]] * df_2.values[:, pidx[1]],
                        columns=lcol)

def Test2(DA,DB):
  MA = DA.as_matrix()
  MB = DB.as_matrix()
  MM = np.zeros((len(MA),len(MA[0])*len(MB[0])))
  Col = []
  for i in range(len(MB[0])):
    for j in range(len(MA[0])):
      MM[:,i*len(MA[0])+j] = MA[:,j]*MB[:,i]
      Col.append('1col_'+str(i+1)+'_2col_'+str(j+1))
  return pd.DataFrame(MM,dtype=int,columns=Col)
```

**results**

[image]

Comment: Nice, a bit of explication wouldn't hurt though!

Comment: using my example the timeit of that function yields `910 µs per loop`

Comment: @Khris run this over a larger dataframe.  OP suggested this was for much larger sets of data.

Comment: Using two larger 100x100 datasets yield `16 ms per loop`, which is amazingly fast compared to the other solutions.

Comment: @Khris not only timing.  But this also handles the column names gracefully.

Comment: @piRSquared My solution seems faster for a dataset with a size similar to the OP's dataset.

Answer (score 6):

You can multiply along the `index` axis your first `df` with each column of the second `df`, this is the ***fastest method*** for big datasets (see below):

```
df = pd.concat([df_1.mul(col[1], axis="index") for col in df_2.iteritems()], axis=1)
# Change the name of the columns
df.columns = ["_".join([i, j]) for j in df_2.columns for i in df_1.columns]
df
       1col_1_2col_1  1col_2_2col_1  1col_3_2col_1  1col_1_2col_2  \
0                  0              0              0              0   
1                  1              0              0              0   
2                  0              0              0              0   

   1col_2_2col_2  1col_3_2col_2  
0              1              0  
1              0              0  
2              0              0
```

#### --> See benchmark for comparisons with other answers to choose the best option for your dataset.

---

## Benchmark

### Functions:

```
def Test2(DA,DB):
  MA = DA.as_matrix()
  MB = DB.as_matrix()
  MM = np.zeros((len(MA),len(MA[0])*len(MB[0])))
  Col = []
  for i in range(len(MB[0])):
    for j in range(len(MA[0])):
      MM[:,i*len(MA[0])+j] = MA[:,j]*MB[:,i]
      Col.append('1col_'+str(i+1)+'_2col_'+str(j+1))
  return pd.DataFrame(MM,dtype=int,columns=Col)

def Test3(df_1, df_2):
    df = pd.concat([df_1.mul(i[1], axis="index") for i in df_2.iteritems()], axis=1)
    df.columns = ["_".join([i,j]) for j in df_2.columns for i in df_1.columns]
    return df

def Test4(df_1,df_2):
    pidx = np.indices((df_1.shape[1], df_2.shape[1])).reshape(2, -1)
    lcol = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df_1.columns, df_2.columns],
                                      names=[df_1.columns.name, df_2.columns.name])
    return pd.DataFrame(df_1.values[:, pidx[0]] * df_2.values[:, pidx[1]],
                 columns=lcol)

def jeanrjc_imp(df_1, df_2):
    df = pd.concat([df_1.mul(‌​i[1], axis="index") for i in df_2.iteritems()], axis=1, keys=df_2.columns) 
    return df
```

### Code:

Sorry, ugly code, the plot at the end matters :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (1000, 600)))
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (1000, 600)))
df_1.columns = ["1col_"+str(i) for i in range(len(df_1.columns))]
df_2.columns = ["2col_"+str(i) for i in range(len(df_2.columns))]
resa = {}
resb = {}
resc = {}
for f, r in zip([Test2, Test3, Test4, jeanrjc_imp], ["T2", "T3", "T4", "T3bis"]):
        resa[r] = []
        resb[r] = []
        resc[r] = []
        for i in [5, 10, 30, 50, 150, 200]:
             a = %timeit -o f(df_1.iloc[:,:i], df_2.iloc[:, :10])
             b = %timeit -o f(df_1.iloc[:,:i], df_2.iloc[:, :50])
             c = %timeit -o f(df_1.iloc[:,:i], df_2.iloc[:, :200])
             resa[r].append(a.best)
             resb[r].append(b.best)
             resc[r].append(c.best)

X = [5, 10, 30, 50, 150, 200]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=[16,5])
for j, (a, r) in enumerate(zip(ax, [resa, resb, resc])):
    for i in r:
        a.plot(X, r[i], label=i)
        a.set_xlabel("df_1 columns #") 
        a.set_title("df_2 columns # = {}".format(["10", "50", "200"][j]))
ax[0].set_ylabel("time(s)")
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Pandas column multiplication]

With `T3b <=> jeanrjc_imp`. Which is a bit faster that Test3.

### Conclusion:

Depending on your dataset size, pick the right function, between Test4 and Test3(b). Given the OP's dataset, `Test3` or `jeanrjc_imp` should be the fastest, and also the shortest to write!

HTH

Comment: My small example yields `2.33 ms per loop`, I'm testing large examples now.

Comment: 100x100 dataset yields around the same performance as my code.

Comment: @Khris the bigger the dataset, the slower your solution will be.

Comment: Your solution has changed from iterating over column names to using `df_2.iteritems()`.  The latter is faster than the former.  And under certain circumstances faster than my solution (like 500 by 100).  However, it is asymmetrically faster.  If the column imbalance went the other way, it's slower.

Comment: Also, you missed an opportunity to be even quicker by using `keys` in the `pd.concat`.    `def jeanrjc_imp(df_1, df_2):
    df = pd.concat([df_1.mul(i[1], axis="index") for i in df_2.iteritems()],
                   axis=1, keys=df_2.columns)
    return df`

Comment: Also, This solution breaks on integer based columns.  Using `keys` fixes that.  That said,  This is a good solution! +1

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks I wasn't aware of the `keys` argument of `pd.concat`, can you elaborate on why it's faster ? Or is it because it gets rid of the double loop to enumerate the column names?

Comment: You only have one loop and that's over the columns of `df_2`.  If the number of columns in `df_2` were much larger than the number of columns in `df_1` then it would be slower because you are looping over a larger number of columns.  So 500 cols by 100 cols is much faster than 100 cols by 500 cols.  Either way, this method seems to faster over a larger portion of meaningful possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

You can use numpy.

Consider this example code, I did modify the variable names, but `Test1()` is essentially your code. I didn't bother create the correct column names in that function though:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = [[1,0,1,1],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1]]
B = [[0,0,1,0],[1,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0]]

DA = pd.DataFrame(A).T
DB = pd.DataFrame(B).T

def Test1(DA,DB):
  E = pd.DataFrame(index=DA.index)
  DAC = [column for column in DA]
  for column in DB:
    C = DA[DAC].multiply(DB[column], axis="index")
    E = E.join(C, lsuffix='_' + str(column))
  return E

def Test2(DA,DB):
  MA = DA.as_matrix()
  MB = DB.as_matrix()
  MM = np.zeros((len(MA),len(MA[0])*len(MB[0])))
  Col = []
  for i in range(len(MB[0])):
    for j in range(len(MA[0])):
      MM[:,i*len(MA[0])+j] = MA[:,j]*MB[:,i]
      Col.append('1col_'+str(i+1)+'_2col_'+str(j+1))
  return pd.DataFrame(MM,dtype=int,columns=Col)

print Test1(DA,DB)
print Test2(DA,DB)
```

Output:

```
   0_1  1_1  2_1  0  1  2  0_3  1_3  2_3  0  1  2  0  1  2
0    0    0    0  1  0  0    1    0    0  1  0  0  1  0  0
1    0    0    0  0  0  0    0    1    1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2    1    1    0  1  1  0    0    0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3    0    0    0  0  0  0    0    0    0  1  0  1  0  0  0
   1col_1_2col_1  1col_1_2col_2  1col_1_2col_3  1col_2_2col_1  1col_2_2col_2  \
0              0              0              0              1              0   
1              0              0              0              0              0   
2              1              1              0              1              1   
3              0              0              0              0              0   

   1col_2_2col_3  1col_3_2col_1  1col_3_2col_2  1col_3_2col_3  1col_4_2col_1  \
0              0              1              0              0              1   
1              0              0              1              1              0   
2              0              0              0              0              0   
3              0              0              0              0              1   

   1col_4_2col_2  1col_4_2col_3  1col_5_2col_1  1col_5_2col_2  1col_5_2col_3  
0              0              0              1              0              0  
1              0              0              0              0              0  
2              0              0              0              0              0  
3              0              1              0              0              0
```

Performance of your function:

```
%timeit(Test1(DA,DB))
100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop
```

Performance of my function:

```
%timeit(Test2(DA,DB))
1000 loops, best of 3: 464 µs per loop
```

It's not beautiful, but it's efficient.