# Combinations of all dataframe columns in python

Tags: python, dataframe, combinations

I have three data frames that have the same index (Countries).
I need to find all the combinations of the three data frames, create new columns with the data frames. Under each of those columns I will have the multiplication of the values from those combinations.

```
Envelope = pd.read_excel("Envelope.xlsx",index_col=0)
Shading = pd.read_excel("Shading.xlsx",index_col=0)
ThermalMass = pd.read_excel("ThermalMass.xlsx",index_col=0)
```

```
#Envelope dataframe
Country         Group(A)  Group(B)  Group(C)                       
France          0.4       0.4       0.2
Brussels        0.8       0.1       0.1
Germany_A       0.3       0.6       0.1
Germany_B       0.2       0.5       0.3

#Shading dataframe            
Country     YeSH  NoSH        
France      0.5   0.5
Brussels    0.6   0.4
Germany_A   0.9   0.1
Germany_B   0.4   0.6

#ThermalMass dataframe             
Country     Heavy   Light         
France       0.4    0.6
Brussels     0.5    0.5
Germany_A    0.3    0.7
Germany_B    0.5    0.5`
```

I tried to use the MultiIndex.from_product

```
all = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([Envelope,Shading,ThermalMass])
```

but the results is only for the titles:

```
print(all)
MultiIndex([('Group(A)', 'YeSH', 'Heavy'),
            ('Group(A)', 'YeSH', 'Light'),
            ('Group(A)', 'NoSH', 'Heavy'),
            ('Group(A)', 'NoSH', 'Light'),
            ('Group(B)', 'YeSH', 'Heavy'),
            ('Group(B)', 'YeSH', 'Light'),
            ('Group(B)', 'NoSH', 'Heavy'),
            ('Group(B)', 'NoSH', 'Light'),
            ('Group(C)', 'YeSH', 'Heavy'),
            ('Group(C)', 'YeSH', 'Light'),
            ('Group(C)', 'NoSH', 'Heavy'),
            ('Group(C)', 'NoSH', 'Light')],
           )
```

I need to have the values for each countries, so it should look like this (3 x 2x 2) = 12 combinations:

```
           Group(A)_YeSH_Heavy  Group(A)_YeSH_Light  Group(A)_NoSH_Heavy   Group(A)_NoSH_Light
Country                 
France       0.08                0.12                 0.08                    0.12 
Brussels     0.24                0.24                 0.16                    0.16
Germany_A    0.081               0.189                0.009                   0.6
Germany_B    0.04                 0.04                0.06                    0.06
```

How can I create the new columns and the combinations of the three dataframes?

Comment: Looks like this solution could work for you: [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259660/create-combination-of-two-pandas-dataframes-in-two-dimensions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
from itertools import product

# Only if country isn't the index yet
Envelope.set_index('Country', drop=True, inplace=True)
Shading.set_index('Country', drop=True, inplace=True)
ThermalMass.set_index('Country', drop=True, inplace=True)

columns = list(product(Envelope.columns, Shading.columns, ThermalMass.columns))
df = pd.concat([Envelope[col[0]] * Shading[col[1]] * ThermalMass[col[2]]
                for col in columns],
               axis='columns')
df.columns = ['_'.join(c for c in col) for col in columns]
```

Output:

```
           Group(A)_YeSH_Heavy  ...  Group(C)_NoSH_Light
Country                         ...                     
France                   0.080  ...                0.060
Brussels                 0.240  ...                0.020
Germany_A                0.081  ...                0.007
Germany_B                0.040  ...                0.090

[4 rows x 12 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967402/how-to-multiply-every-column-of-one-pandas-dataframe-with-every-column-of-anothe), here is a vectorized appraoch that uses MultiIndex.

```
pidx = np.indices((Envelope.shape[1], Shading.shape[1], ThermalMass.shape[1])).reshape(3, -1)
lcol = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([Envelope, Shading, ThermalMass])
pd.DataFrame(Envelope.values[:, pidx[0]] * Shading.values[:, pidx[1]] * ThermalMass.values[:, pidx[2]],
            columns=lcol, index=Envelope.index)
```

Gives:

```
          Group(A)                      Group(B)                       \
              YeSH          NoSH            YeSH          NoSH          
             Heavy  Light  Heavy  Light    Heavy  Light  Heavy  Light   
Country                                                                 
France       0.080  0.120  0.080  0.120    0.080  0.120  0.080  0.120   
Brussels     0.240  0.240  0.160  0.160    0.030  0.030  0.020  0.020   
Germany_A    0.081  0.189  0.009  0.021    0.162  0.378  0.018  0.042   
Germany_B    0.040  0.040  0.060  0.060    0.100  0.100  0.150  0.150   

          Group(C)                       
              YeSH          NoSH         
             Heavy  Light  Heavy  Light  
Country                                  
France       0.040  0.060  0.040  0.060  
Brussels     0.030  0.030  0.020  0.020  
Germany_A    0.027  0.063  0.003  0.007  
Germany_B    0.060  0.060  0.090  0.090
```