# What is an efficient method to multiple each column in PySpark dataframe by every other column, i.e., Combinations without repetition

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to calculate the second-order interactions between two different objects, i.e., "keywords," so I need to multiply every column in PySpark data frame by every other column in an efficient manner. For instance, if I have 780 keywords, then there will be more than 300,000 potential combinations (without repetition). So I will multiple Keyword #1 * Keyword #2, and Keyword #1 * Keyword #3, and so on. My data frame has about 10,000 rows. In addition, not all keywords are present, so I need to keep track of my column names.

My data frame looks like this:

| ID | keywords_1 | keywords_2 | keywords_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 574086 | 3 | 1 | 5 |
| 505724 | 4 | 3 | 7 |

And I need to have a resulting data frame:

| ID | keywords_1 * keywords_2 | keywords_1 * keywords_3 | keywords_2 * keywords_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 574086 | 3 | 15 | 5 |
| 505724 | 12 | 28 | 21 |

What would be an efficient manner to do so?

(I have tried different pandas UDFs but they are very inefficient, time consuming and have memory issues.)

Answer (score 3):

here is one way you can try:

```
cols = df.columns[1:]
import itertools
out = (df.select("ID",*[(F.col(i[0])*F.col(i[1])).alias('*'.join(i)) 
                         for i in itertools.combinations(cols,2)]))
```

---

```
out.show()

+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    ID|keywords_1*keywords_2|keywords_1*keywords_3|keywords_2*keywords_3|
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|574086|                    3|                   15|                    5|
|505724|                   12|                   28|                   21|
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

A similar way as @anky's answer using `itertools`, but here I used `selectExpr` to make the syntax slightly simpler, by taking advantage of the fact that the expression is the same as the column name:

```
import itertools

cols = df.columns[1:]

df2 = df.selectExpr(
    'ID',
    *[f'{pair} as `{pair}`'
         for pair in [' * '.join(i) for i in itertools.combinations(cols, 2)]
     ]
)

df2.show()
+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|    ID|keywords_1 * keywords_2|keywords_1 * keywords_3|keywords_2 * keywords_3|
+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|574086|                    3.0|                   15.0|                    5.0|
|505724|                   12.0|                   28.0|                   21.0|
+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

But note that in general it's not a good idea to have reserved characters in column names. That's why I had to wrap it in backticks. You may want to consider using underscore (`_`) instead of asterisk.

To group by another column, you can do

```
import itertools

cols = df.columns[1:]

df2 = df.groupBy('ID').agg(
    *[F.expr(f'sum({pair}) as `{pair}`')
         for pair in [' * '.join(i) for i in itertools.combinations(cols, 2)]
     ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tested both methods and they both have about the same performance (with @anky's answer  being slightly faster). I didn't want to complicate the question too much, but there is a secondary ID column, 'group_number' (so one ID can have multiple rows of different group numbers.) I need to group by the primary ID and then perform the element-wise multiplication. How could I do that with either code sample? I actually use underscores. I just used "*" as a shorthand.

Comment: Timing it on AWS cluster (master: m5.xlarge - 4 cores, 16 G mem; 5X workers: r4.4xlarge - 16 cores, 122G mem), this method takes more than 2 hours to calculate 5,000 combinations. So 300,000 combinations is going to take a long time to calculate. Any ideas on how to speed this up?

Comment: @DavidComfort not sure... algorithm-wise it seems simple enough to have been optimized, so I guess you'll need more cores. Or you should also think about whether all the combinations are necessary.

Comment: @anky that probably would involve the same amount of calculations, so I don't think that'll really help the OP

Answer (score 0):

After testing the two different PySpark solutions, I also tested a method using pandas and it turns out this solution is much faster than either one of the PySpark solutions. I am calculating the interaction between a fairly large number of columns (~780) which generates more than 300,000 combinations.

```
df_second_order = df.groupby('ID').apply(
lambda x: pd.concat([x.mul(i[1], axis="index") for i in x.iteritems()],
                    axis=1,
                    keys=x.columns
                    )).reset_index()
```

This solution generates duplicate combinations of keywords, but it is straightforward to filter out the duplicate combinations. I also tried a list comprehension (with just the non-duplicated combinations of columns) instead of the generator `x.iteritems()` and it is considerably slower.

One consideration is that the generated data frames can be quite large (24G; I also had to change the data type to `int8` to minimize the memory needed). One can simply loop through a certain number of rows, save the generated data frame and then delete unneeded data frames before starting a new iteration. Using this method, I was able to generate 300,000 combinations of more than 780 columns for a data frame of almost 1 million rows in 3 hours and 30 minutes.

This solution is based upon the solution presented at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38970709/6287730